# C++ function will not print array to console in reverse

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on homework for my c++ class we have just started arrays. I cannot figure out why the function `reverse_array()` does not print to the console when the function `show_array()` prints to the console without an issue. I've attempted googling the issue without success. I am just beginning c++ so it could be something small that I'm overlooking,. I appreciate any help.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

double dbval[5];

void fill_array(int x, double dbval[]);
void show_array(int x, double dbval[]);
void reverse_array(int x, double dbval[]);

int main(){


    int x = 0;


    fill_array(x,dbval);
    show_array(x,dbval);
    reverse_array(x,dbval);

    return 0;
}
void fill_array(int x, double dbval[]){

    int count = 0;

    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        cin >> dbval[x];
        if(!cin){
        break;
        }
    }
    for(x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        count = count + 1;
        }

    cout << "Entries " <<int(count);
    cout <<endl;
}

void show_array(int x, double dbval[]){
    for (x = 0; x<5;x++){
        cout << dbval[x] << " ";
   }
    cout << endl;
}
void reverse_array(int x, double dbval[]){
    for(x = 5; x < 5; x--){
        cout << dbval[x] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop for(x = 5; x < 5 ; x--) failed because it did not satisfy your condition the first time it checked (x = 5, but it needs to be smaller than 5 to enter the loop)
Change to this:

```
void reverse_array(int x, double dbval[]){
    for(x = 4; x >= 0 ; x--){
        cout << dbval[x] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: I will give it a shot, now that its been pointed out it seems very obvious. Thanks

Comment: I applied the changes and it still doesn't cout to the console for that function. Its not throwing any errors in the compiler that i can see

Comment: @GusRobins I have run your code on C++ editor online, and it worked. Please check again

Comment: it worked now I had the code from before you edited your answer all set now. thanks for all the help